# How to use web crypto to import an encrypted RSA private key

Tags: javascript, openssl, rsa, webcrypto-api

Someone generated a RSA key pair with the following code using nodejs

```html
export function generateAsymmetric2048KeyPairAsync: (passphrase) {
    const options = {
        modulusLength: 2048,
        publicExponent: 0x10001,
        publicKeyEncoding: {
            type: 'spki',
            format: 'pem'
        },
        privateKeyEncoding: {
            type: 'pkcs8',
            format: 'pem',
            cipher: 'aes-256-cbc',
            passphrase: passphrase
        }
    };

    const generateKeyPairAsync = promisify(generateKeyPair);
    return generateKeyPairAsync('rsa', options);
}
```

Or you can use the following openssl command to generate the same key pairs

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out private_key.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
openssl rsa -pubout -in private_key.pem -out public_key.pem
openssl pkey -in private_key.pem -out private_key_en.pem -aes256
```

My task is importing them to browser environment with Web Crypto API. I'm able to import the public key, but having trouble for the encoded private key. The following snippet is the code I'm trying to use. iv and salt are required BufferArray for the algorithms' parameter object, but I don't know what to assign for them.

```html
  const iv                // assign a 16b array here
  const salt              // assign a 16b array here
  const encodedPPKBuffer  // read the private key here
  const passphrase        // read the passphrase here
  
  const pbkAlgo = {
    name: "PBKDF2",
    salt: salt, 
    iterations: 100000,
    hash: "SHA-256"
  }
  
  const aesAlgo = { 
    name: "AES-CBC", 
    iv: iv, 
    length: 256
  };
  
  const rsaAlgo = {
    name: "RSA-OAEP",
    modulusLength: 2048,
    publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
    hash: "SHA-256",
  };
  
  function getKeyMaterial() {
    const enc = new TextEncoder();
    return window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
      "raw",
      enc.encode(passphrase),
      {name: "PBKDF2"},
      false,
      ["deriveBits", "deriveKey"]
    );
  }
  
  async function getUnwrappingKey() {
    const keyMaterial = await getKeyMaterial();
    return window.crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
      pbkAlgo,
      keyMaterial,
      aesAlgo,
      true,
      [ "wrapKey", "unwrapKey" ]
    );
  }
  
  async function unwrapPrivateKey(wrappedKey) {
    const unwrappingKey = await getUnwrappingKey();

    const ppk = await window.crypto.subtle.unwrapKey(
      "pkcs8",               // import format
      encodedPPKBuffer,      // ArrayBuffer representing key to unwrap
      unwrappingKey,         // CryptoKey representing key encryption key
      aesAlgo,               // algorithm params for key encryption key
      rsaAlgo,         
      true,                  // extractability of key to unwrap
      ["decrypt"]     // key usages for key to unwrap
    );
    return ppk;
  }
```

When I was following the web crypto api document for unwrapping a "pkcs8" key: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/unwrapKey
It specifies that we must match the original salt and IV when encrypting the key. I suspect this is the problem. I don't know what's the original salt and IV. Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: I can use the second code snippet to unwrap a private generated by web crypto with a reversed process. But it require me to have the same iv and salt values. I notice that the unwrap-able key generated by web crypto is 1232 bytes long but the key generated by node crypto is 1329 bytes long.